# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Closes when I try to add or open a project which contains .edmx files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I have a problem adding ADO.Net Entity Data Model to my existing project, or even while opening a project which contains *.edmx files.(In my case ) Visual Studio closes automatically. I see the following error in the event log every time this happens
Googled the specific error but drew a blank.

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4016 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (70207A3E) (80131506)
```

I run Visual Studio Team System 2008 with SP1 on Windows Vista Enterprise

I also have Power Commands set up. Wondering if that could be a possible source of the problem?

Help on this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

```
Bhupesh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstalled VS2008 and installed it again. Am now able to work with all kinds of solutions, projects and files. Have yet to pin point if it was any particular add-on that I had installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your solution's .suo file. This file contains local user settings for the solution and files it contains. Sometimes this file can get corrupted and cause this problem.

Comment: Tried this in one situation, it does not apply in another situation... I've done this to solve similar issues I've faced. In my case there are no suo files when I'm opening an existing project, this is a project I've downloaded dropthings, though I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the .edmx files as the dropthings solution does not seem to have any entity framework related files.